# ORA-00942 cannot find table

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00942

I ran these statements:

```
create table SAMPLE(
     ID INT
     );
     
INSERT INTO SAMPLE VALUES(1);
COMMIT;

GRANT INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE ON SAMPLE TO NEWLEC;
COMMIT;
```

But Eclipse says cannot find the table.

[image]

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Which user were you connected as when you created the table?

Answer (score 2):

You are connecting as the `newlec` user, and unqualified references to tables will look for them in *that* schema, not under other users.

You can qualify the table name:

```
SELECT * FROM real_owner.SAMPLE
```

For example, if you were connected as HR when you created the table, you would do:

```
SELECT * FROM HR.SAMPLE
```

---

You could also create a public synonym, which is probably overkill and can cause other issues and confusion; or create a private synonym for the `newlec` user which points to the rea table, e.g.:

```
CREATE SYNONYM SAMPLE FOR real_owner.SAMPLE;
SELECT * FROM SAMPLE;
```

so the unqualified query now sees the synonym, and through that the real table owned by someone else. Or you could set your `current_schema` after logon:

```
ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=real_owner;
SELECT * FROM SAMPLE;
```

so all unqualified queries now see objects owned by that user, not `newlec`.

However, if this is a basic assignment on a beginner course then you are probably just expected to qualify the name.

Comment: OH MY GOD thank you.. i solve this error by qualify the table name.. thank you!!

Comment: Why wouldn't you accept the answer, then, @HONG?